# Get the underlying type of a std::variant

Tags: c++, variant, c++17

Quick question:

Is it possible to get the underlying type used by a `std::variant` at runtime ?

My first guess was to use `decltype()` like this:

```
    std::variant<int, float> v;
    v = 12;
    std::vector<decltype(v)> vec;
```

But the declared type for my vector is `std::vector<std::variant<int, float>>` not `std::vector<int>`.

Any idea of how I can achieve that ? :)

Comment: i.e. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative

Comment: @EdHeal `holds_alternative` checks if a variant currently holds a given type  (which is nice), but does not return the underlying type directly :/

Comment: depending of what you want, `std::visit` might help.

Comment: In the case of `std::variant<int,float>` there is very little advantage over just using a `double`, which can hold all `int`s exactly and all `float`s exactly. Also, GCC reports that `sizeof(std::variant<int,float>) == sizeof(double)` so there also isn't any extra memory used for storing `double`s. Of course, this doesn't mean the question is invalid since you may have just simplified your use case for the sake of the question.

Comment: @SirGuy "there is very little advantage over just using a double, which can hold all ints exactly" It's actually implementation defined, as the size of an `int` could be equal to the size of a `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the underlying type used by a std::variant at runtime ?

Yes it definitely is

> Any idea of how I can achieve that ?

Your try to achieve something very different than "get the underlying type used by a std::variant at runtime", as define `std::vector` type at runtime. This is very different issue and definitely not possible in this form as template instantiation happens at compile time. Closest solution would be to use `std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>` and use different vector based on runtime information from your variable `v`